# Expose javascript variable in jQuery plugin while maintaining chainability?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

The problem with my plugin is that i need to **expose** `var chart` and maintain chainability. How can i accomplish this? This is the first plugin i wrote and i don't know if chainability is really important to preserve. Thanks.

**Html piece**

```
<div id="chart1" class="chart"></div>
<div id="chart2" class="chart"></div>
```

**Plugin invocation**

```
$("div").chart();
```

**Plugin definition**

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.chart = function(options) {

       return this.each() // Maintain chainability
       {
           // Stuff, ajax call and then...
           var chart = new Highcharts(options);
           // Expose each chart variable for each container (<div>)
       }

    };

})(jQuery);
```

**EDIT**: added clarification about `chart` variable.

Comment: You should attach it to the main jQuery object: `$.chart`

Comment: @JosephSilber No. jQuery plugins have to be defined on the prototype, `$.fn = jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype`.

Comment: @RobW - I didn't say he should attach his plugin there - he's doing it correctly. I meant that he should **expose** his variable through that. Read his question again.

Comment: @JosephSilber The ability to maintain multiple charts is still not achieved. It's better to attach the chart to the element itself, such as `$(this).data('chart-of-element', chart);` (within the `this.each` loop).

Comment: @RobW - I might have misread the question, but it seems to me he wants to expose the main `chart` variable (the one he calls global).

Comment: Perhaps more clarity is required... what is the `chart` (global) variable? It's not clear on why you need it global. But understanding why may be crucial to helping us give you a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should read [Plugins/Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) if you havent already. There are some good ideas in there.

Second, you can try something like this:

```
$.fn.chart = function(options)
{
    if(options=='get_charts')
        return charts;
    else
    {
        // Stuff, ajax call and then...
        var chart = new Highcharts(options);
    }
}
```

This would then be called normally with `$('#something').charts({});` or `$('#something').charts('get_charts');`

Comment: Just as additional info, you don't need the `else{}`. Just use `if(options=='get_charts'){return charts;}` and below the normal code. `return` already ends the function there (if `if` evaluates true).

Comment: True. It is purely a stylistic decision. I like it when most of the method  body is on the same indentation. It helps me to identify blocks and control flow more easily.